# shopping basket analysis in python with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing transaction data. Each row represents one transaction and the columns indicate whether a product has been bought from a category (categories are A-F) or not (one =  yes, zero = no). Now I would like to compute the pairs of transactions within each category. My dataframe looks as follows:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  
1  1  0  0  0  0   
1  0  1  1  0  0
```

The output should be a matrix counting each pairs of the categories in the dataframe like so:

```
  A B C D E F
A 4 2 1 0 4 2
B 5 6 7 3 5 1
C 1 6 5 8 7 9
D ...
E ...
F ...
```

Anyone knows a solution on how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the dot product with its transpose:

```
df.T.dot(df)
Out: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F
A  2  1  1  1  0  0
B  1  1  0  0  0  0
C  1  0  1  1  0  0
D  1  0  1  1  0  0
E  0  0  0  0  0  0
F  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Note that looking for pairwise occurrences is not scalable though. You might want to look at [apriori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm).